# Bug in displaying previous year's election results

Tags: bug, election, deleted-accounts

Today I visited the [Workplace election result page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election) to find  who got selected as the moderators.

But in the results of the year 2018, I found something strange. It displays the username **Snow**. [Snow](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/124851/snow) has been a member in The Workplace only for 4 months.

[image]

I suspect there was an old user with the same username and their account got deleted as it leads to a [Page not found](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/44108) page.

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: That user was previously a moderator, deleted their account, and recreated it with the same profile picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [@Catija's comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/8?tab=nomination#comment553902_170545):

> "For anyone concerned, I'm happy to confirm that this is the same Snow who was a moderator here previously and I'm glad to see him standing in the election to be nominated. While he certainly could have requested reinstatement, I respect his decision to run in the election. – Catija♦ Mar 16 at 13:34".

It's the same person, and people are allowed to have the same name and delete their account - there's nothing to fix.

Additional comment details:

> "@Mari-LouA, I've added that brief history now. Refer to the Election 2018 page for a snapshot of my rep and stats at my prior election. I didn't keep any data from when I left because I didn't feel as though I especially wanted it. – Snow Mar 16 at 7:05

> @Richard I'm not going through the reinstatement process because I'd feel bad about going on hiatus for a year and just demanding my old job back. If people want me and respect me enough to vote, that's great. If they don't, I'll accept that. I don't believe that people would respect me as much if I just snapped my finger and got my diamond back. – Snow Mar 16 at 7:09

> How can we confirm you are the real Snow? Has anyone been able to confirm the account? – Draken Mar 16 at 9:52